# I load the ng-options with object, but I would like the matching ng-model as a single value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I use an array structered like this:

```
[
{"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"},
{"name": "Åland Islands", "code": "AX"},
{"name": "Albania", "code": "AL"},
{"name": "Algeria", "code": "DZ"},...
```

To load a select with ng-options:

```
  <select class="form-control" id="country" ng-model="val" ng-options="country.name for country in countryList">
                    </select>
```

Indeed the select display the list of the countries by name.
I want the list to select an option by the country code and not by the object {name ... code..} as it works now. How could I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the [DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) for for `ng-options`,

it says,

**for array data sources:**

> label for value in array
>
> select as label for value in array
>
> label group by group for value in array
>
> label disable when disable for value in array
>
> label group by group for value in array track by trackexpr
>
> label disable when disable for value in array track by trackexpr
>
> label for value in array | orderBy:orderexpr track by trackexpr (for including a filter with track by)

so you need to modify your code as below,

```
 <select class="form-control" id="country" ng-model="val" ng-options="country.code as country.name for country in countryList">
```

here `ng-options="country.code as country.name for country in countryList"`

> `countryList` - is the data source.
>
> `country` - is the single item in the `countryList`.
>
> `country.name` - is the name property of the `country` this is the label in option.
>
> `country.code` - is the selected value in the `select` box.

here is the [Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O6apiUbw16ojruVYW4eG?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can select by code by following code,

```
<select id="country" ng-model="val" ng-options="country.code as country.name for country in countryList"></select>
```

and if you want the whole selected object, which you may want to process for other reasons

```
<select id="country" ng-model="mySelectedCountry" ng-options="country as country.name for country in countryList">"></select>
```